# The new user first selected mine as his answer, then choose another

Tags: discussion

I recently gave an answer and then the OP selected mine as selected answer. He even thanked me in comments as this is doing his work. Again, after sometimes, a new user gave an answer which is exact as mine. Now the OP has selected his as the answer. I guess he doesn't know that there can only be one accepted answer. Should I leave this issue or can i get any advice?

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it. Maybe the OP changed his mind.

Comment: The OP changed the accepted answer after the other answer was updated with more information. It seems they find that more useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to [c-array-to-pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345663/c-array-to-pointers/37345754#37345754) the answer that is currently accepted is not the exact same as yours. The newly accepted answer goes into some explanation of what is going on. Your answer while it may help provide a solution does not go into the same level of detail as the other answer which is most likely why the user changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

This could happen due to more than one possible cause:

1. The OP changes his mind
2. The OP does not know that he can only choose one answer
3. The OP *accidentally* clicks the other answer when browsing on his post again
4. some other reasons which I do not know

In your case, as often happen to many other people, it might not be clear which is the case.

In any case, it is the OP's prerogative to choose which answer as the accepted answer. That being said, it is also your choice to put a comment to him - say, if you want to remind him that only *one* answer can be accepted and that will impact the reputation of both the acceptor and the answerer (if this be your concern).

If he replies your comment, then you get clarified what is the case. If he does not reply, then you probably won't get your answer accepted again.

In any case, my advice is don't be bothered too much, but move on! :) You will start to get used to it. Remember that people can exercise his choice of actions as much as we do. As long as we do it responsibly, that should be good enough.

Comment: The OP is a fresh new user. He thanked me for a good answer. I beleive he thinks that more than one answer can be accepted so he did. I commented him right now

Comment: @AnishSharma ah yes, that could be the case since the OP is a new user, but remember to leave the final choice to him.

Comment: I sure will. Maybe he will learn later

Comment: s/some other reasons which I do not know/cat got on the computer again

Comment: @NathanOliver that is certainly one of the reasons! ;)